# How to get CameraX event when PreviewView is ready

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

I'm trying to achieve effect with animation, but only after preview view is active. One of the reasons is also to avoid flickering after camera is binded.

I've managed to do it using reflection (androidx.camera.core.UseCase) , but on some devices onUseCaseActive is called multiple times in strange order. It's first in ACTIVE state, then it switches to INACTIVE and it is called multiple times and at the end is ACTIVE state.

So my actual question: Is there any way to get CameraX callbacks so I can manage my state differently accordingly to state of camera?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76224276/9585130

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to know when the camera preview first displays on `PreviewView`, you can use [`PreviewView.getPreviewStreamState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView#getPreviewStreamState()), it's a `LiveData` instance that emits either [`STREAMING`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView.StreamState#STREAMING) or [`IDLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView.StreamState#IDLE) when the preview is showing or not respectively.

As the documentation states, depending on `PreviewView`'s implementation mode, the accuracy of the signal for when the preview starts differs. For [`COMPATIBLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView.ImplementationMode#COMPATIBLE) mode, receiving the stream state `STREAMING` accurately implies that the preview has started, [`PERFORMANCE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView.ImplementationMode#PERFORMANCE) mode is less accurate.

Toward the end of your question, you generalized it to include other CameraX use cases as well. So for `ImageAnalysis`, you know it's active once you receive the first camera frame through its attached [`Analyzer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis.Analyzer). As for `ImageCapture`, you receive a success/failure callback after taking a picture through one of its capture callbacks [`OnImageCapturedCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback) and [`OnImageSavedCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback).